# Solution Verification: Using the Open Mapping Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I would like to answer the following question
[image]

**My solution:** Suppose that $f$ is non-constant. By the open mapping theorem the image of $f$ is open.  Now consider the mapping of $a \rightarrow f(a)=u(a)+iv(a)$. Since the map is open, there exists a disc $D(f(a),r)$ in the image of attained by $f$. Thus the point $u(a)+ \frac{1}{2}r+iv(a)$ is in the image attained by $f$ and hence there exists $b$ s.t. $b \rightarrow u(a)+\frac{1}{2}r+iv(a)$. This is contradiction as $a$ was assumed to be local maximum for $Re(f)$ and from the abov work we see that $Re(b)>Re(a)$. Therefore, $f$ must be constant.

**My question:** Is this correct?

Comment: What if $f(a)=-1$ and $r=1$? Then $f(a)+\frac{1}{2}r=-\frac{1}{2}$, the modulus of which is smaller than the modulus of $-1$. So you don't have a contradiction.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos the question talks about the local maximum of Re(f) not |Re(f)|. Does it not?

Comment: Oh, right! In that case, your solution is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your verifying this for me, my question has been answered :)